# Constraint layout is not visible in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

My problem I created an app in the android studio, its .xml file (design) is not visible although its text is visible to me, Please provide a solution

Here is how it looks:

[image: here is how it looks]

my text file(.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="137dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="217dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="67dp" />
```

///Please provide solution for this

Comment: Can you post your XML code (click on the text tab, rather than the design tab)

Comment: Which compileSdkVersion are you using?

Comment: posted my xml code

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle(Module: app)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution for your problem is just change the theme of your style from

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

change to

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: where should I change this?? i my .xml file?

Comment: go to res>values>styles.xml then change the style and build the project

Comment: and can you post the build.gradle(Module:app)?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try changing your `API Version in Editor`

**EDIT**

Try `syncing project`

[image]

Comment: try sync project

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidate and restart.

```
File->Invalidate and Restart
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have added below dependency in your build.gradle(Module:app) file.

```
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```